# Retrieve only specific keys from firebase real-time database

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

```
    ref.child(eid).addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

            if(snapshot.exists()){
                val user = snapshot.getValue(UserModel::class.java)
            }
        }
    })
```

Currently, the code that I use above retrieves all the keys of the eid child. How can I retrieve only specific keys from the eid child?

The eid child has too much data. I don't need all keys.

Thanks

Comment: just a dictionary of keys, nothing special

Answer (score 1):

The only way is to filter data, you can use `limitToFirst()` which would return a limited number of nodes from the beginning of the list, or even you can use `limitToLast()` that will retrieve limited number of nodes from the end of the list.

For example:

```
ref.child(eid).limitToFirst(10).addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

            if(snapshot.exists()){
                val user = snapshot.getValue(UserModel::class.java)
            }
        }
    })
```

Or another way if you want to retrieve a specific value, then you can just use `equalTo()`:

```
ref.child(eid).orderByChild("name").equalTo("Peter").addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

            if(snapshot.exists()){
                val user = snapshot.getValue(UserModel::class.java)
            }
        }
    })
```

The above query would work, if you have the following database:

```
eid
 random_id
   name: Peter
```

Check the following documentation for more information:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#filtering_data